# Проверять значение на уникальность, пока оно не станет уникальным

Tags: php, циклы

Извините за глупый вопрос, но не знал как сформулировать вопрос. 
В общем пытаюсь проверить seo url на уникальность. Если такая запись в базе есть то добавляется "-1", "-2" и т.д. пока запись не будет уникальной.
Сделал вот таким способом

```
 if($product['keyword'] && !empty($product['keyword']) ) {

    for ($i=1; $i < 4; $i++) { 
            $keyword = $product['keyword'];
            $keyword_isset = getIssetAlias($keyword, $connect);
            if($keyword_isset) {
                $keyword = $keyword.'-'.$i;
                $keyword_isset = getIssetAlias($keyword, $connect);
                if(!$keyword_isset) $product['keyword'] = $keyword;
            } 
    }

}
```

Но здесь есть ограничение на ко-во раз выполнения цикла. Подскажите как сделать выполнения цикла пока значение не станет уникальным. Функция getIssetAlias возвращает true если значение существует в базе, и false если не существует.

Comment: что такое циклы - знаем?

Comment: знаем, но как применить их данной ситуации не знаю

Comment: используйте цикл while

Comment: пример в данной ситуации с циклом while можете написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product = $product['keyword']
$i = 1; 

while(getIssetAlias($product, $connect)){
    $product = $product['keyword'] . '-' . $i++;
}
```

при условии что **getIssetAlias($product, $connect)** - возвращает **true/false**